# Python: Pass a key value argument through try except block

Tags: python, apache-spark, exception

I am trying to call this function

```
def retry(function, **kwargs):
    max_tries = 3
    for i in range(max_tries):
        try:
            logger.info(f"try#  {i + 1}")
            logger.info(f"executing function")
            function(**kwargs)
            break
        except Exception as error:
            if i < max_tries - 1:
                time.sleep(10)
                logger.info(f"Error Reason: {error}")
                logger.info(f"retrying #  {i + 1}")
                continue
```

and through this function i want to call

the function create_view is as follows:

```
def create_view(**kwargs) -> None:
    a = kwargs['a']
    b = kwargs['b']

    logger.info(f"a is {a} for b as {b} ")
```

while calling

```
retry(create_view(),
          a=1,
          b="x",
          )
```

i am getting error:
source_db_tbl = kwargs['a']
KeyError: 'a'
please help

I tried

```
retry(create_view(),
          a=1,
          b="x",
          )
```

and expected
a is 1 for b as x

Comment: You are not passing a function but the result of calling it (which errors since the arguments are not set). Use `retry(create_view, a=...)`

Comment: Also `retry()` has no `*args` but you are using them for calling the function.

Comment: @Alankrita what you're trying to do from the create_view?

Comment: I have created a dummy function in order to replicate the original but basically i would need the parameters passed as keys

Comment: Your `retry` now works, but you need to pass the original function correctly: `retry(create_view, a=1, b="x")` or with a existing dict `retry(create_view, **create_view_kwargs)`